# How do I filter Photo Spheres on Google Maps by date range?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to find recent Photo Spheres on Google Maps (not street view).

Is it possible to specify a date range when viewing Photo Spheres?

EDIT: It seems like this is not possible.